# Collision in randomly generated String

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I have a function which gives me randomly a combination of letters from A-Z and numbers from 0-9. I want to generate 20000 keys out of this. My question is now that I want to determine the probability to create unique keys.

I tried it the following:

$$nCr(36 + 4 - 1,4) = 82251$$

I want to find out how random `20000` keys are, so:

$$\frac{20000}{82251} = 0.2431$$

So the probability that I get a non unique key is $24.31$ percentage.

Are these thoughts correct?

I appreciate your answer!